Saving all text that appears in R session?
I want to make it so that all text (code that is run, errors produced) that appeared on the screen during my R session are saved in a notepad file.
I am trying the following way:
sink("save.txt", split=TRUE)

# r code here

sink()

However, this is not fully saving all errors.
Is there some alternate way to do this?

Why do you need this? Other approaches might be more convenient. I'm having a hard time imagining a scenario where your proposed approach should be used.

How will you be running the R script? Through a command line? RStudio? Something else?

@Roland Totally agreed, but just for completeness I can think of three such scenarios off the top of my head: (1) implementing your own testing framework, (2) implementing your own report generator, (3) implementing your own ‘callr’.

@KonradRudolph Granted. But I don't expect those to be the goal here since OP needed to ask this question.

Just look at and copy the Example section of ?sink.

Here is an example adapted from ?sink:
# Set the working directory to current's file directory

setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))

# Specify the output file path
output_file <- "log_output.txt"

# Open a file connection for capturing messages and errors
zz <- file(output_file, open = "wt")
# open sinks
sink(zz, type = "message") # Redirect messages and errors to the file
sink(zz)                   # Redirect standard output to the file 

# Code block whose output and errors will be logged
cat("This is standard output\n")
cat("Test\n")
try(log("a"))  # Example of an error

# Reset the sink and close the file connection
sink(type = "message")
sink()
close(zz)

# Confirm the file was saved and display its path
if (file.exists(output_file)) {
  cat("Output saved to:", normalizePath(output_file), "\n")
} else {
  cat("Error: Log file not created.\n")
}

creates "log_output.txt":
This is standard output
Test
Error in log("a") : Nicht-numerisches Argument für mathematische Funktion


Assuming you want to log the whole terminal outputs of this R-Script "sink.R". There is another way.
sink.R
cat("This is standard output\n")
cat("Test")
paste(x y) # will produce an error

We can create a separate logger R-Script:
logger.R
log_code <- function(filename) {
 
  # Ensure the script exists
  if (!file.exists(filename)) {
    stop("The script file does not exist: ", filename)
  }
  log_file_name <- paste0(filename, "_logfile.txt")
  # Use tools::Rcmd to run the script with BATCH mode and redirect output to the log file
  tools::Rcmd(paste("BATCH --no-save --no-restore", filename, log_file_name))
  
}

log_code("sink.R")

which produces this output textfile (whole code including errors from terminal):
sink.R_logfile.txt
R version 4.4.2 (2024-10-31 ucrt) -- "Pile of Leaves"
Copyright (C) 2024 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64

R ist freie Software und kommt OHNE JEGLICHE GARANTIE.
Sie sind eingeladen, es unter bestimmten Bedingungen weiter zu verbreiten.
Tippen Sie 'license()' or 'licence()' für Details dazu.

R ist ein Gemeinschaftsprojekt mit vielen Beitragenden.
Tippen Sie 'contributors()' für mehr Information und 'citation()',
um zu erfahren, wie R oder R packages in Publikationen zitiert werden können.

Tippen Sie 'demo()' für einige Demos, 'help()' für on-line Hilfe, oder
'help.start()' für eine HTML Browserschnittstelle zur Hilfe.
Tippen Sie 'q()', um R zu verlassen.

> 
> cat("This is standard output\n")
This is standard output
> cat("Test")
Test> paste(x y) # will produce an error
Fehler: unerwartetes Symbol in "paste(x y"
Ausführung angehalten


This is because errors and warnings are directed to the 'stderr', not the 'stdout'.
To capture both 'stdout' and 'stderr' in an R session, you can use sink() in combination with file() for redirection.

This answer could be improved by providing sample code that achieves what you describe and which then shows the result of running the code.
